# Where can I find the list of verbs for catkin?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The official list of verbs for `catkin` as obtained from `catkin -h` is

```
  [build | clean | config | create | env | init | list | locate | profile]
```

I stumbled upon a few additional verbs:

- `run-tests` : Builds and runs the tests
- `test`: Runs and prints the test results (I think)

I'm guessing these aren't the full list of catkin verbs available.  Where can I find all available verbs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366131/where-can-i-find-the-list-of-verbs-for-catkin?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "additional verbs" you mention are actually not verbs. They are *aliases*.

From the `catkin_tools` documentation ([here](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/verb_customization.html)):

> The `catkin` command allows you to define your own verb “aliases” which expand to more complex expressions including built-in verbs, command-line options, and other verb aliases. These are processed before any other command-line processing takes place, and can be useful for making certain use patterns more convenient.

On my system, running `catkin --list-aliases` returns:

```
b: build
bt: b --this
install: config --install
ls: list
p: create pkg
run_tests: build --verbose --catkin-make-args run_tests --
test: build --verbose --make-args test --
```

Note the last two lines, which are the aliases you mention.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1